# Having trouble creating an azure sql database dependency for my project

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I am getting the following errors when I try to create the **azure sql** dependency:

> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException:
>
> Unsupported resourceID '/subscriptions/988c01a5-638b-4385-9cfd-9bc40f3ad17c/resourcegroups/OnlineShopping20210607161055ResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/2021GRP28'.
> Failed to configure dependency Azure SQL Database mssql1.

I have deployed this application a few months back under a different account and with a different resource group, app service and subscription. Could that be the issue because the resource group mentioned above in the error code is from the other account and if so, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Location might not be supported for the resource type.

You can see the registration status and register a resource provider namespace through the portal.

From the portal, select All services.

Select all services. Select Subscriptions.

[image]

Select subscriptions

[image]

From the list of subscriptions, select the subscription you want to use for registering the resource provider. Select subscription to register resource provider

[image]

For your subscription, select Resource providers.

[image]

Look at the list of resource providers, and if necessary, select the Register link to register the resource provider of the type you're trying to deploy.

[image]

Comment: I fixed it. I deleted some json files in the properties folder that were pertaining to the server dependencies. One of those json files had code that contained the old resource group that I had connected to the project previously so I figured that deleting those files would resolve those issue and it did thankfully.